# How to count all online members using v13?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I'm currently trying to get all online members in **a specific guild** and count them. I already tried these methods:

```js
let onlineMembers = (await interaction.guild.members.fetch()).filter(
      (member) => !member.user.bot && member.user.presence.status !== "offline"
    );
```

and

```js
let onlineMembers = interaction.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status !== "offline").size
```

I also tried fetching all members first and filter the result like this:

```js
const allMembers = await interaction.guild.members.fetch();
const onlineMembers = allMembers.filter(member => !member.user.bot && member.presence.status !== "offline");
```

But I'm always getting this exception:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

So I went looking for a solution and I noticed that I manually have to activate all **intents** I want my bot to use. I "activated" the needed intents in my `index.js` like this:

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES
    ],
});
```

But this didn't fix my problem either.

In the Discord Developer Portal I also enabled both privileged gateway intents:

[image: Privileged Gateway Intents activated]

And who could have guessed...it still doesn't work. It's weird, because for some members it's working but I need it to work for every member.

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching this information changed in V13

This code will generate an Object with the properties `online`, `idle` and `dnd`:

```js
let GUILD_MEMBERS = await client.guilds.cache.get(config.ids.serverID).members.fetch({ withPresences: true })

var onlineMembers = {
 online: await GUILD_MEMBERS.filter((online) => online.presence?.status === "online").size,
 idle: await GUILD_MEMBERS.filter((online) => online.presence?.status === "idle").size,
 dnd: await GUILD_MEMBERS.filter((online) => online.presence?.status === "dnd").size
}
```

Let me know, if this works for you

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! And yes, you solved it :D Finally... Thanks ^^ Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: Tbh, I had the same problem, and could not find a solution myself. I asked on the discord, and after some back and forth I got this exact answer. Took me hours to too, since I could not find any documentation on that myself. Maybe someone else found something tho :/

Comment: Ah okay haha :D And thanks again ^^ Would you mind adding me on Discord if I need your help again?